# How to match and add a class name using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to match the class attribute of `<html>` tag and to add a class name using [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/preg_replace).
Here is what I tried so far:

```
$content = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" class="dummy"><head></head><body></body></html>';
$pattern = '/< *html[^>]*class *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i';
if(preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches)){
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, '<html class="$1 my-custom-class">', $content);
}
echo htmlentities($content);
```

But, I got only this returned:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html class="dummy my-custom-class">"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

The attribute `lang="en"` is dropped out and the tag is appended with the duplicates like `">">`. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: can you write the desired output ?

Comment: @Mike I was going to link to it lol

Comment: why don't you like to try this http://in3.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php#79074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code it works, perfectly well :)

```
<?php

$content = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" class="dummy"><head></head><body></body></html>';
$pattern = '/(<html.*class="([^"]+)"[^>]*>)/i';

$callback_fn = 'process';

$content=preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback_fn, $content);


function process($matches) {

$matches[1]=str_replace($matches[2],$matches[2]." @ My Own Class", $matches[1]);

return $matches[1];

}


echo htmlentities($content);

?>
```

Comment: Great! It did work, but it has a glitch. It is not working when the class name is space like `class="  "`. This is my code fix `function process($matches) { $find = 'class="'.$matches[2].'"'; $replace = 'class="'.$matches[2].' my-class-name"'; $matches[1] = str_replace($find, $replace, $matches[1]); return $matches[1]; }`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the * in pattern for regex way

Use this pattern

```
/<html[^>]*class *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i
```

I suggest use [**`Dom parser`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) for parsing the  html

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html="<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en' class='dummy'><head></head><body></body></html>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);


foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('html') as $node) {

    $node->setAttribute('class','dummy my-custom-class');

}

$html=$dom->saveHTML();
echo $html;
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="dummy my-custom-class"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but removing the `*` is not working as expected. And regarding with `DomDocument`, I got these errors `Warning: domdocument::domdocument() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given` and `Fatal error: Call to undefined method domdocument::loadHTML()`. I don't want to use `DomDocument`because it needs additional server requirements and my code will be run on every page load as it is invoked in the output buffering handler. `DomDocument` needs `php_domxml.dll` disabled on the server.

Comment: The purpose is to add a respective class name for each IE version to the `<html>` tag from the output handler.

Comment: @Sithu just add the **libxml_use_internal_errors(true);** to disable the internal errors.